# Can't CD to Desktop anymore

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, desktop, onedrive

In my Windows 10 box, I can't `cd` to `Desktop` anymore.

```
C:\Users\me>cd Desktop
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\me>
```

What's wrong with my computer?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and include result of `dir` command

Comment: @gronostaj There is no file suspected to be my Desktop in my dir result

Comment: Have you relocated folders or otherwise changed any permissions or attributes in `C:\Users\me`?

Comment: @JinKwon - Please still provide the results of the `dir` command.

Comment: @Ramhound Please see my answer. The mystery solved with another mystery laid.

Comment: FYI, my own answer converted to a comment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your Desktop directory has been moved to a different location. To find its new location:

1. Create a new file on the Desktop
2. Right-click the file and click **Properties**
3. On the *General* tab make note of the file's path. It will include the Desktop directory's current location.

Comment: To fix it do you just rename/move the folder?

Comment: @wjandrea No. If you move or rename it, everything on the Desktop will disappear (although not be deleted) and Windows will create a new directory in place of the moved/renamed one. This page explains the correct process for changing the actual location of the Desktop directory (the example uses the Downloads directory but it's the same process): https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-change-the-location-of-user-folders-in-windows-10/ (somehow I can never find the official Microsoft documentation on this when I need it)

Comment: @Micheal Nice. I think these are the official instructions, though for "My Documents": [Configuration of the My Documents folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/310746/configuration-of-the-my-documents-folder) under "How to Change the My Documents Folder Storage Location"

Comment: Why would it have moved?  My Desktop sure is under %HOMEPATH%.

Comment: It could be moved by the user or by some policy (e.g. group policy) the user's profile is affected by.

Comment: When I tried what [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1502576/207024) suggested, I found, Oh Lord!, my `Destkop` is currently targeting C:\Users\<me>\OneDrive\Desktop I'm not sure why this happening.

Comment: Your desktop in located there because of your OneDrive settings ([Desktop Folder Protection](https://www.howtogeek.com/363720/how-to-enable-microsofts-new-onedrive-folder-protection-in-windows/)).

Comment: @Ramhound If it ever starts doing that on its own, I'll nuke it from high orbit. Programs shouldn't touch fundamental locations like this.

Comment: @Mast - You could just disable the feature instead of trying to uninstall OneDrive on Windows 10 (you will find that will be very difficult).  Considering this feature is optional, and enabled by the user, it can easily be disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound Uninstalling OneDrive was actually pretty easy on my last Win10 install (where it was installed by default for some reason). The feature may be optional, but I would expect a warning that enabling the feature is going to move entire folders, especially the fundamental ones.

Answer (score 4):

This solution might be late but you have to write:
cd onedrive
then cd desktop

Hopefully this helps :D

Comment: I recently linked my desktop to OneDrive could not find the desktop in the directory now i know it is in OneDrive

Answer (score 0):

Open the file properties and copy the path and place the path after the `cd` command.

For example if the path is `C:\Users\YourName\OneDrive\Desktop` then the command should be:

```ps
cd C:\Users\YourName\OneDrive\Desktop
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Find Desktop file in My PC folder -> right click - Properties -> copy the path given -> then give this command "cd path-copied"

Found this late but can be helpful!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

easy way to fix this issue

```
cd  /d d:
```

[image]